# Minimum distance from a point (in 3D space) to a 3D convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

I'm stuck on a problem to find the minimum distance from a point (in 3D space) to a 3D convex hull. Does anyone know an algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: In order not to use brute force, we need to know what kind of information (neighbours, vertices, etc) you store.

Comment: @Ripi2 Hi, so the point $p$ is stored as $p = [p_x \hspace{0.1cm} p_y \hspace{0.1cm} p_z]$ and the convex hull is stored as an $N \times 3$ matrix where each row corresponds to a point in 3D space that is a vertex of the hull.

Comment: How do you store faces/edges? There's no further info by only vertices coordinates.

Comment: I assume minimum distance will be at a point that the distance/segment is vertical to both surfaces